# using if statements with command line parameters in c

Tags: c, if-statement, command-line

I am having trouble with getting my if statements to work with parameters from the command line. I get an error saying, 'comparison between pointer and integer ('char *' and 'int')' every time. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is the description for what I have to do:

This program will read a parameter from the command line and translate it to the name of the corresponding month.  I.e. if you run the program with the following parameter:

It will print the following message:

The month is 'April'.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argv[1] == 1){
        printf("You entered the number 1.");
    } else {
        printf("You entered a different number.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `argv[1]` is a pointer to a null terminated string, it won't make much sense to compare the *pointer* with `1`.

Comment: You want `if (argv[1][0] == '1' && argv [1][1] == '\0')`

Answer (score 5):

The parameters passed on the command line are strings, so you need to use `strcmp` to compare them.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc > 1 && (strcmp(argv[1],"1") == 0)){
        printf("You entered the number 1.");
    } else {
        printf("You entered a different number.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent hours last night trying to figure out how to do it so it means a lot!

Comment: @AntonioOcasio You may also want to use `atoi` or `strtol` to convert the string to an integer if that's what you want to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler is right - you are comparing `char *` and `int`.

You have to either convert `argv[1]` to `int` (e.g. with `strol()`) or convert `1` to `char *` (by adding quotes - `"1"`) and then compare with `strcmp()` instead of `==`.

And checking number of arguments in `argc` is also something you should do, when working with arguments. (thanks @Ingo Leonhardt)

Comment: adding quotes won't fix the code; `if( argv[1] == "1" )` still doesn't work

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Oh, correct. With that you need to change comparision to `strcmp()` instead of `==`.

Comment: right, and check for argc. Maybe you want t edit your answer

Comment: sorry for being obtrusive. Single quotes ere only valid if you use them in the way @vladimir hast suggested in his answer

Comment: Thanks @IngoLeonhardt, I had to try that `'1'`, because I thought it will work :) and it doesn't, so I deleted that part.

Answer (score 1):

Argv returns pointer to array of chars, so your programm must looks like:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if(argv[1][0] == '1'){
            printf("You entered the number 1.");
        } else {
            printf("You entered a different number.");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Or you can use `atoi` `(man 2 atoi)` function to convert ascii array to int like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(atoi(argv[1]) == 1){
        printf("You entered the number 1.");
    } else {
        printf("You entered a different number.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but better check for argc first

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your command line parameter like a integer, you must modify the type with atoi

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(atoi(argv[1]) == 1){
        printf("You entered the number 1.");
    } else {
        printf("You entered a different number.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```